# search result not work went add tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, searchbar

Search bar is woking very well until I add custom tableview cell. It breaks when I search a keyword matching with a array. When I search wrong, it doesn't break.

```
var filteredArray = [String]()
var searchController = UISearchController()
var result = UITableViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: result)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    result.tableView.delegate = self
    result.tableView.dataSource = self
    result.tableView.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

}

//config seachbar
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredArray = array.filter( { (array : String) -> Bool in
        if array.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!)
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }

    })
    result.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and this is a tableview cellForRow

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SanPhamTableViewCell


    //    fill data into cell   
    if tableView == result.tableView
    {
        cell.name.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.img.image = UIImage(named:  ArrayImage[indexPath.row])

        cell.price.text = ArrayPrice[indexPath.row]
        cell.price.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        cell.desc.text = arrayDesc[indexPath.row]
        cell.desc.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    else
    {
        cell.name.text = arrayName[indexPath.row]
        cell.img.image = UIImage(named:  arrayImage[indexPath.row])

        cell.price.text = arrayPrice[indexPath.row]
        cell.price.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        cell.desc.text = arrayDesc[indexPath.row]
        cell.desc.isUserInteractionEnabled = false        }

    return cell
}
```

[image: this is a error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the cell like this in `viewDidLoad`, replace:

```
result.tableView.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

with:

```
result.tableView.register(SanPhamTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

//

**Edit :** for xib

```
result.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SanPhamTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: Cell)
```

Comment: You can't register two different cell types for the same identifier.

Comment: the other register is wrong this a replacement for it

Comment: Sorry, thought you meant in addition to. Maybe clarify that is is a replacement, not an addition.

Comment: i'd try but it have a new problem with 
              cell.name.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
 "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: do you have xib cell or created it programmatically

Comment: i create custom cell name SanPhamTableViewCell

Comment: ''NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/dung/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6116553D-C64A-48E2-A3AD-FE5F463BF46C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D7C3C4FF-8DCC-447D-9106-7B4E52FE82D9/Search.app> (loaded)' with name 'SanPhamTableViewCell''' it still not work

Comment: as a note either you should have **SanPhamTableViewCell.swift** with **SanPhamTableViewCell.xib**  or only **SanPhamTableViewCell** with subviews created programmatically

Comment: 'cell.name.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row]Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' it still is an error

Comment: you should create xib for it to work and link the labels to the xib

Comment: yeah, let me try

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how are you making the `SanPhamTableViewCell`, But if you are using a custom nib then that nib must also be registered with `tableView`

```
result.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SanPhamTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Comment: "Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(UINib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String)" i try and it error like this

Comment: Are you setting up the identifier in the nib file for SanPhamTableViewCell ?